# How to assign large concatenated string in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to assign a large text more than 8000 characters in SQL server

Thanks,
Vara Prasad.M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the [max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158%28SQL.90%29.aspx) types but beware that any intermediate expressions will be `varchar(8000)` (or `nvarchar(4000)`) unless they involve the `(n)varchar(max)` type

```
DECLARE @maxtype varchar(max)

--on the right, never above 8000
SET @maxtype = REPLICATE('a', 6000) + REPLICATE('b', 6000)
SELECT LEN(@maxtype) --8000

--here, there is a max on the right
SET @maxtype = REPLICATE(CAST('a' AS varchar(max)), 6000) + REPLICATE('b', 6000)
SELECT LEN(@maxtype) --12000
```

Comment: if i use nvarchar(max) it is taking upto 9998 characters only. But in my concatenated string it is more than 9998 characters in this case what i have to do?

Comment: @Vara Prasad.M: well, you have some wrong intermediate value somewhere like I said. Without code, I can't tell you. if you run my code here you'll see 12000 (I'll change the replicate)

Comment: For example the concatenated Comma separated value is set @in_CustomerIds='11465385,11465386,11465387,11465388,11465389,11465390,11465391,11465392,11465393,11465394,11465395,11465396,11465397,11465399,1466463,11466464,11466465,11466466,11466467,11466468,11466470,11466471,11466472,11466473,....' but I am unable to get all the characters only 9998 characters only getting. how to get all the characters that are specified as above in Quotations?

Comment: What did I say? You have an intermediate value that is wrong somewhere. Simple. And is this one big list that is only 9998 long?

Comment: it contains more than that count means greater than 9998 characters. can you explain in brief?

Comment: @Vara Prasad.M: The question is answered and I've demonstrated that you can store large strings in SQL Server. Job done. Ask a new question and provide full information there, with all relevant code.

Comment: @gbn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2032/discussion-between-vara-prasad-m-and-gbn)

Comment: @VaraPrasad.M, i am having the same problem my string is more bigger, but it is truncated when i put it in the table. can you share your experience how you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type.

Comment: if i use nvarchar(max) it is taking upto 9998 characters only. But in my concatenated string it is more than 9998 characters in this case what i have to do?

Comment: @Vara: Showing us your code would be a step in the right direction.